# ubuntu 16.04, sound problem, dummy output

Tags: sound, 16.04

I install ubuntu 16.04 Lts a few days ago, and everything works great until yesterday..

Yesterday a turn the pc on and go to youtube and no sound at all.

I past all day try to solve this problem.. no success!!

Anyone can help my with this? I,m new in the Linux world.

cumps,
Daniel